Fetching Next.js 14 API route throws a 404 error even though I use route.ts
I'm using Next.js 14.2.3 and trying to fetch the /api/tmp API route from the chat.tsx component, but the error 404 is thrown even though I use route.ts. Why?
EDIT: Is it because chat.tsx is a client component? If yes, how can I fetch an API route in a client-side component?
chat.tsx:
"use client";

export default function Chat() {
  /.../

  const test = await fetch("/api/tmp", {
    method: "GET",
  });

  /.../
}

route.ts:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: any) {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello World" }, { status: 200 });
}

Structure:
src
 |__app
     |__components
     |      |__chat.tsx
     |__hooks
     |__pages
     |    |__api
     |        |__tmp
     |            |__route.ts
     |__shared
     |__styles
     |__types
     |__layout.tsx
     |__page.tsx

Terminal:
GET /api/tmp 404 in 61ms


looks like the api/temp dir is nested inside pages dir. Have you tried "/pages/api/tmp" as the endpoint for the get request?

@3CE Read the accepted answer below carefully. In my case, the error was thrown because I used the wrong path.

Problem :

Fetching Next.js 14 API route throws a 404 error even though I use route.ts

Cause :

Improper URL

Solution :

NextJS is file-system based router where folders are used to define routes
NextJS uses folder name as URL hence, Change URL to /pages/api/tmp
/api/tmp causes NextJS to look under app/api/tmp thats why it gives you 404
If you want URL to be /api/tmp then just keep api folder under app (app/api).

Read More :

Route Handlers : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

Creating Routes : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes#creating-routes



If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)

